# iPhone: what combination of gestures should I use to manipulate a 3D model?

Tags: gestures, virtual-reality, augmented-reality

I am working on an AR map where I load a model onto the screen, and I'd like to allow the user to do the following:

1. Scale size
2. Move up/own/sideways, so basically X/Y axes.
3. Move forward/backward, z axis

So for scaling I think of pinching, for moving on the X/Y axes one finger pan/drag.

What would be a good gesture to use for the 3rd use case?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use [Human Interface Design guidelines for AR](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/augmented-reality/#Designing-object-interactions) and [Common gestures](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/gestures):

For **scaling** they suggest this gesture:

> With two hands, pinch and drag together or apart

For **movement in X/Y axes**:

> Limit movement to the two-dimensional surface on which the object rests.

So, basically, touch and drag should move the object in two axes by default (generally, horizontal, not sure if it's X/Z or what in your case);

And then **for movement on Z axis** you could use some additional interaction controls. For example a handle that appears when you touch (select) the object that, when dragged by, could change z-axis. Something like what, for example, Maya uses to control dragging at specific axes (those colorful arrows can be used to drag the object on sepcific axis):

[image]

Comment: Play around with the Scaniverse app on iOS, it's a good example of how AR works out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following gesture:

- Two Finger Vertical Pan/Drag

Although it would require a short tutorial for the user, since case 1 and 2 logically use the most known gestures, the third case requires a sort of an explanation